# CoreData database syncing without iCloud?

Tags: ios, core-data, replication, synchronization, icloud

With iCloud, you can sync your CoreData databases across multiple devices. This works by means of SQLite creating a transaction log that is replicated via the cloud. I like that mechanism, by I don't want to tie it to iCloud and Apple's servers.

Is there a way to enable this transaction log and manually replicate it using custom code and servers under my control?

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment the transaction logs are not exposed by any API. You can look at them on your Mac if you have iCloud enabled (they live in `~/Library/Mobile Documents/`) to try to figure out how Apple is doing this and replicate it yourself. Sounds like a very difficult problem though.